# Can't figure out small part in python class definition

Tags: python

My code is almost done but I can't figure out one thing. Here is the problem:

> Write a class named Car that has the following data attributes:
>
> - `__year_model`
> - `__make`
> - `__speed`
>
> The Car class should have an `__init__` method that accepted the car's year model and make as arguments. These values should be assigned to the object's `__year_model` and `__make` data attributes. It should also assign 0 to the `__speed` data attribute. The class should also have the following methods:
>
> - accelerate: The accelerate method should add 5 to the speed data attribute each time it is called.
> - brake: the brake method should subtract 5 from the speed data attribute each time it is called.
> - get_speed: The get_speed method should return the current speed
>
> Next, design a program that creates a Car object and then calls the accelerate method five times. After each call to the accelerate method, get the current speed of the car and display it. Then call the brake method five times and do the same. However, when the car is braked and speed >0 it should display an error message and reset speed back to 0.

This last line is the part I'm having difficulties with. It properly adds 5 and subtracts 5 but doesn't display an error message when it is less than 0. Here is my code of the class definition and the code that tests it. Thank you for any help.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, year_model, make):
        self.__year_model = year_model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = 0

    ############# year_model################
    def setYear_model(self, year_model):
        self.__year_model = year_model

    def getYear_model(self):
        return self.__year_model

   ############# Make################
    def setMake(self, make):
        self.__make = make

    def getMake(self):
        return self.make

   ############# speed################
    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        if speed < 0:
            print("Speed cannot be negative")
        else:
            self.__speed = speed

    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.__speed

    def accelerate(self):
        self.__speed += 5
        return self.__speed

    def brake(self):
        self.__speed -= 5
        return self.__speed
    
    ############# str ############
    def __str__(self):
        return "Make : " + self.__make + ", Model Year :" + \
            self.__year_model + ", speed = " + str(self.__speed)



import ag_CarDefinition

def main():
    # Create an instance of Car
    my_car = ag_CarDefinition.Car("2008", "Honda Accord")
    print(my_car)
    print("my_car after instantiating:\n", my_car)

    my_car.setSpeed(2)
    print("my_car after my_car.setSpeed(2):\n", my_car)
    # Accelerate 5 times
    print ("car is accelerating: ")
    for i in range(5):
        my_car.accelerate()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print()
    # Brake 7 times
    print ("car is braking: ")
    for i in range(7):
        my_car.brake()
        print ("Current speed: ", my_car.getSpeed())

    print("my_car values at program end:\n", my_car)


main()
```

Comment: What is it with CS courses teaching getters and setters with private variables in Python? That's Java-style code, not Python.

Comment: `if self.__speed < 0: self.__speed = 0; print "some warning"`

Comment: Also, no need to copy paste your assignment here, just the specific thing you are having issues with

Comment: Okay it does set it back to 0 but now it displays "some warning" on each line, how do I get it to only display when it resets the speed to 0?

Comment: @Tony where should I put this? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Whoops you should have self.brake to check self.__speed before doing the subtraction.  So in `brake()` the code should read 
`if (self.__speed - 5) < 0: 
print("going negative") 
self.__speed=0`  With each on their own line

Comment: @Tony I did that and now it doesn't subtract 5 at all. :(

Comment: @Tony nevermind I figured it out!

Comment: good job, i forgot to put that part!  else: self.__speed -= 5

Comment: As a note by the way, you don't want to return private variables if you have getters and setters.  there's no reason for brake, or accelerate to have return statements given how you're using them.